# storybook doesn't work with node7 with webpack + babel?

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, storybook

I am using node7.2.1 and npm 5.6.0 in a react project. The project is managed by `webpack2`. I tried to add `storybook` in this project but failed on compilation. The error I got when run `storybook` is:

```
TheFrontEnd/node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/build-static.js:31
async function compileManager(managerConfig, managerStartTime) {
      ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:78:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

I know there is something to do with es6 syntax. But I have created a `.babelrc` file under `.storybook/` directory but it doesn't seem to help. The babel file I added is:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "stage-2",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-async-to-generator",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "add-module-exports",
    "react-hot-loader/babel"
  ]
}
```

The webpack file for storybook is: (.storybook/webpack.config.js)

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    // your custom plugins
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      // add your custom rules.
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Storybook unfortunately requires Node 8.6+: https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/blob/next/package.json#L190-L193

https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/6510

Storybook has required at least Node 8+ since version 3.0 at the beginning of 2018:
https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/89af8fe76f21bd89d7c86c6134bce030873122bc/package.json

Node 7, Node 6 and below are therefore out of the picture for a long time now.